# neither i owe you any money nor you owe me any money

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the better way to say

> now neither I owe you any money nor you owe me any money

Does the following sentence indicates the same?

> Our accounts are clear now

Is there a better way of saying it?

Comment: "We're even" or "We're square".

Comment: awesome! thanks, But i need more formal sentence

Comment: Writing advice may be off topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say "We don't owe each other any money." or "We're clear of our debt to each other."

"Our accounts are clear now." speaks specifically about accounts being clear and might not be common enough to be easily understood.

Answer (score 3):

**"We are square"** isn't terribly informal and should be acceptable in formal settings.

From [Oxford:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/square)

> *Adj, 5* (of two people) owing nothing to each other.

- ‘an acknowledgement that we are square’
- ‘‘I need you to do one more thing for me,’ Xavier said. ‘Then we're square.’’
- ‘So in my eyes, we're square. All debts settled.’

Answer (score 1):

I'd go "Now neither of us owe the other any money"